# Windows 10 UWP APP: Is there a way to have Devicefamily specific XAML for phones and tablets?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I know, that it is possible to use different XAML for Desktop and Mobile in folders.
Is there a way do choose also Phone and Tablet in different folders?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can implement different view based esclusively on the family.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706137.aspx

The families supported by UWP are: desktop/mobile/IoT/XBOX. The phone is mobile. And you cannot get the tablet, because you can have an touch-screen ultrabook with or without the keyboard. You can detect the "tablet mode" and write some XAML to implement Adaptive UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design

You have to manage all device view( Tablate ,Mobile,Desktop and etc)